Find the equation of the line(s) simultaneously tangent to $y = −x^4$ and $y = (x + \frac{5}{2})^4 + 16$
This is a A-level further maths question. To find a line which is simultaneously tangent to both quartic equations

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

If $(x_0,y_0)$ on the first equation has the same slope as $(x_1,y_1)$ on the second equation, can you find a (simple) relationship between $x_0$ and $x_1$? The tangent lines $y=mx+c$ through $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ must then have the same $c$ value. Can you find a (fourth order) equation satisfied by c? This equation has two real integer solutions.

I would start by finding the derivatives of the two functions.
$f(x)=-x^4\\
g(x)=\left(x+\frac52\right)^4+16$
$f'(x)=-4x^3\\
g'(x)=4\left(x+\frac52\right)^3$
Then we can write the equations for the tangent lines of each function in point-slope form.
Tangent of $f(x)$: $\;\;y=-4a^3(x-a)+f(a)$, where $a$ is some constant.
Tangent of $g(x)$: $\;\;y=4\left(b+\frac52\right)^3(x-b)+g(b)$, where $b$ is another constant.
Next, we expand and simplify the tangent line equations to convert them to the form $y=mx+c$. This useful because it will allow us to equate the $m$ terms together and the $c$ terms together to create a system of equations, which we can then use to solve for $a$ and $b$ (as suggested by Paul's comment).
Tangent of $f(x)$ in slope-intercept form: $\;\;y=-4a^3x+3a^4$
Tangent of $g(x)$ in slope-intercept form: $\;\;y=4\left(b+\frac52\right)^3x+\left(-3b^4-20b^3-\frac{75}{2}b^2+\frac{881}{16}\right)$
Now we can write a system of equations that equates both $m$ terms and both $c$ terms so we can solve for $a$ and $b$.
\begin{cases}
{-4a^3=4\left(b+\frac52\right)^3  \;\; \Leftarrow \;\; \text{these are the two $m$ terms}\\
3a^4=-3b^4-20b^3-\frac{75}{2}b^2+\frac{881}{16} \;\; \Leftarrow \;\; \text{these are the two $c$ terms}}
\end{cases}
I decided to solve the first equation for $a$, then substitute it into the second equation to solve for the value of $b$, which we can use later to figure out the value of $a$.
$-4a^3=4\left(b+\frac52\right)^3\\
-a^3=\left(b+\frac52\right)^3\\
a=-b-\frac52$
Now we substitute the expression for $a$ into the second equation to solve for $b$.
$3(-b-\frac52)^4=-3b^4-20b^3-\frac{75}{2}b^2+\frac{881}{16}\\
3b^4+30b^3+\frac{225}{2}b^2+\frac{375}{2}b+\frac{1875}{16}=-3b^4-20b^3-\frac{75}{2}b^2+\frac{881}{16}\\
6b^4+50b^3+150b^2+\frac{375}{2}b+\frac{994}{16}=0$
At this point, I didn't know how to solve the quartic equation algebraically, so I graphed it and saw that $b=-\frac72$ and $-\frac12$. Since we know that $a=-b-\frac52$, we can substitute the $b$-values to find $a$.
$a=-\left(-\frac72\right)-\frac52\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;a=1\\
a=-\left(-\frac12\right)-\frac52\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;a=-2$
Now that we know all the values of $a$ and $b$, we can plug them back into the original tangent line functions to get their exact equations.
Tangent lines of $f(x)$:
$y=-4(1)^3(x-1)+f(1)\;\;\,\Rightarrow\Rightarrow\Rightarrow\Rightarrow\;\; y=-4(x-1)-1\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\boxed{y=-4x+3}\\
y=-4(-2)^3(x-(-2))+f(-2)\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;y=32(x+2)-16\;\;\Rightarrow\;\; \boxed{y=32x+48}$
Tangent lines of $g(x)$:
$y=4\left((-\frac72)+\frac52\right)^3(x-(-\frac72))+g(-\frac72)\;\; \Rightarrow\;\;y=-4(x+\frac72)+17\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\boxed{y=-4x+3}\\
y=4\left((-\frac12)+\frac52\right)^3(x-(-\frac12))+g(-\frac12)\;\; \Rightarrow\;\;y=32(x+\frac12)+32\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\boxed{y=32x+48}$
As expected, the tangent lines of $f(x)$ are equal to the tangents of $g(x)$.
